# Set onclicklistener to fragment

Tags: android

I have Activity. In Activity I have fragment ("MyFragment"). In fragment I have listView.

Then in code I do next:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.my_fragment).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        //SomeAction
    }
});
```

But this onClick doesn't work. I think because ListView cover whole fragment.

Then I set to list view next:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

But it's not working. How to make fragment to catch all click events?

Comment: What are you trying to click? List View items? If so you don't need to do any of this.

Comment: I'm trying to click on fragment, I don't want list view to catch my clicks

Comment: If the ListView is covering the whole Fragment, why not just use the ListView's OnItemClickListener since it already works, rather than struggle to create another click listener?

Comment: @Sam - That would work but in the event he has only 1 or 2 items the entire fragment wouldn't be clickable. Just those 2 items

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a ListView in your fragment, it's a better idea to use [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html). OnitemClickListener are better integrated.
The you just have to override the OnListItem listener

Here are good tutorials : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Here is an example :

```
public class ListMenu extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {

private String[] strList = { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4" };
OnMenuSelectedListener mCallback;

public interface OnMenuSelectedListener  {
    public void onMenuSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, strList));

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallback = (OnMenuSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


    mCallback.onMenuSelected(position);
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}

}
```

Comment: This one too (I cannot post more than 2 links): http://neilgoodman.net/2012/01/29/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-1/